# What is the Presto query to get the data type of a particular column in a particular table?

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, presto, sqldatatypes

Or what is the Hive query to get the data type of a particular column in a particular table?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`typeof`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/conversion.html?highlight=typeof#typeof) function to get the type of a column or expression:

```sql
SELECT typeof(column) FROM t
```

Comment: This seems to only work if there is data in the table. What if this query returned 0 rows? What if there is no data in the table? How do we get the type of a column?